# Copy data between the Workbooks basing on match condition (without opening the Source)

Tags: vba, excel

I Have been working on the recent post that I have posted a while ago, but apparently, the condition in the code still does not succeed.

I want to copy the data from some Source Workbook to my currently opened workbook in which I work, but only under condition if the defined name in my current workbook matches the first 18 characters of the variables in column N:N of the Source workbook from where I want to copy the data from.

I have used the help of brainac, who helped me modify that condition - it starts after the line of the stars, however, it still does not work. Without having that condition to match defined name (in my current workbook) with variables in column N:N (in the SourceWorkbook), the code works fine - so I have a problem with constructing the condition.

I added the line saying: ActiveArray.Close, to have the Source Workbook closed at the end of the process, however, The only result it returns is opening of the Source Workbook and that's all. The match and copy are not executed at all and no error occurs. Any idea why it could be? I appreciate any response.

```
    Sub Copy_Data()

            Dim ActiveArray As Variant
            Dim SourceWBpath As Variant
            Dim i As Long
            endRow = 1003
            Const l_MyDefinedName As String = "MyDefinedName"
            Const s_ColumnToMatch As String = "N:N"                'The column in the Source Workbook to be match with My defined name

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            Set ActiveArray = ActiveWorkbook
            Set SourceWBpath= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("E1")      'Cell with path to the Source Workbook
            Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(SourceWBpath)
            Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

         '**************************Copy Workbook content to this sheet****************************************************
     With SourceWB
      Dim i As Long
      endRow = 1003
      For i = 2 To endRow
        Dim rngFound As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngFound =SourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(s_ColumnToMatch).Find(What:=l_MyDefinedName & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
      Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                rngFound.Parent.Range("A2:Y1900").Copy
                ActiveArray.Sheets("Test").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close

                End If

        End With
        End Sub
```

Comment: A couple things.... 1. Disable your error handling so you can see what's going on (comment out the line `On Error Resume Next`). 2. You need `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` in there at some point, even if you're closing the workbook it's just a best practice to turn that back on after turning it off. 3. I don't see where you've added `ActiveArray.Close`? Is part of your macro missing?

Comment: If it neither copies nor closes ActiveArray you may not find that string. Put a `Debug.Print` somewhere to check, e.g. `If Not ...` `Else` `Debug.Print "Not Found"`. BTW, with that `For` loop you run the same search 1003 times. Is it on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this.

```
Sub GetData_Example1()
' It will copy the Header row also (the last two arguments are True)
' Change the last argument to False if you not want to copy the header row
    GetData ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xls", "Sheet1", _
            "A1:C5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), True, True
End Sub

Option Explicit


Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
            If UseHeaderRow Then
                For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                    TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                    rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
                Next lCount
                TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            Else
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            End If
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function Array_Sort(ArrayList As Variant) As Variant
    Dim aCnt As Integer, bCnt As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String

    For aCnt = LBound(ArrayList) To UBound(ArrayList) - 1
        For bCnt = aCnt + 1 To UBound(ArrayList)
            If ArrayList(aCnt) > ArrayList(bCnt) Then
                tempStr = ArrayList(bCnt)
                ArrayList(bCnt) = ArrayList(aCnt)
                ArrayList(aCnt) = tempStr
            End If
        Next bCnt
    Next aCnt
    Array_Sort = ArrayList
End Function
```